# How to play multiple video one after one?

Tags: android

I am developing a project in android in which i have 4 frame-layout in Scroll-view in one activity and i want to play mp4 video in each frame layout one by one continuously in same activity can any one give me the source code for that i will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

In the onCreate() method,

```
videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);

videoView.setonCompletionListener(this);

videoArray = new ArrayList<String>;

addVideoPaths();

startVideo();
```

Function addVideoPaths() :

```
public void addVideoPaths(){

  videoArray.add(<yourpath>);
  videoArray.add(<yourpath>);

  .
  .

  videoArray.add(<yourpath>);
}
```

In the overridden onCompletionMethod:

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(){

 videoView.stopPlayBack();
 startVideo();
}
```

Similarly in the onError():

```
@Override
public void onError(){

 videoView.stopPlayBack();
 startVideo();
}
```

The startVideo():

```
startVideo(){

   Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoArray.get(0));
   videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
   videoView.start();
   videoArray.remove(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void startVideo() {
        if(videoArray.size()>0){
            myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoArray.get(0));
            myVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            myVideoView.start();
            myVideoView.requestFocus();
            videoArray.remove(0);
        }else {
           finish();
        }

    }
```